# Two of the same image displayed by thickbox gallery at once

Tags: javascript, thickbox

I am having a problem where occasionally two of the same images will load up, one on top of the other so both are showing. This only happens on the first image that loads up and is very intermittent. Has anyone else run into this problem using thickbox? Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I had the same problem and just solved it.
We had multiple galleries on one page, all seperated by the `rel='' tag` to group them.
We ran into the `"two images on first click"` problem as well.

Our php code was not smart enough to realize it was including the javascript more than once. So by only including the .js files once on the page, the problem was solved.

Maybe this is not a solution for you but it worked for us so I thougt I'd share.